# Where do brew, cask, pip, npm, composer, et cetera get their stuff from, and what prevents malware?

Tags: npm, composer-php, homebrew, package

If I install stuff using `brew` or `brew cask` (on macOS) or `npm` or `pip` or `composer` or similar package/code/library managers, I have always wondered:

1. Where do they get their content from, who or what entity is managing or facilitating or hosting all those software or packages or modules or libraries?
2. Are there any checks, safety filters, audits, validation, or other mechanisms that prevent malware in the packages or libaries that are being distributed though these package managers?

Answer (score 1):

## Composer

List of packages is stored at https://packagist.org/, but there are only metadata.  Packages are downloaded directly from related repositories (usually GitHub or GitLab), Packagist does not store or analyze its content. So while it may look a bit scary, the security model is based on trust to the vendor or direct code review. There is no magic solution which will pretend that it protects you from malware - you need to think what you're doing and what dependencies you're including into your project (or at least use some malware scanner on your own).